# Image Differencing: Ignore translational movement

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm looking for some insight into what the best approach might be to my problem.
I'm comparing two separate images for differences, but I'm running into a problem with small translational movements.

I have a "gospel" image which is the "gold standard" per se:
[gospel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luj69.png)

Then I have multiple different taken images to compare against.
Here's an example: [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqfgs.png)

Here's an example difference image showing my problem: [difference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JBzI.png)

As you can see, they are quite small. The way that I am differencing the images now is by first resizing the images to 32x32, manually decreasing the contrast by 100 and then applying a blur using OpenCV.

After, I am using skimage's 'structural_integrity' function to subtract and quantify the differences between the images. The rest is purely for viewing.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity

def change_contrast(img, level):
    img = Image.fromarray(img)
    factor = (259 * (level + 255)) / (255 * (259 - level))
    def contrast(c):
        return 128 + factor * (c - 128)
    return np.asarray(img.point(contrast))

# Open and preprocess the images
image_orig = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
image = cv2.resize(image, (32, 32))
image = change_contrast(image_orig, -100)
image = cv2.blur(image, (5, 5))
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gospel_orig = cv2.imread(GOSPEL_PATH)
gospel = cv2.resize(gospel_orig, (32, 32))
gospel = change_contrast(gospel, -100)
gospel = cv2.blur(gospel, (5, 5))
gospel = cv2.cvtColor(gospel, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Get image similarities and an output difference image
(score, diff) = structural_similarity(image, gospel, full=True)
print("Image similarity", score)

diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")

# Viewing stuff below
thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

filled_gospel = cv2.cvtColor(gospel, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 40:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.drawContours(filled_gospel, [c], 0, (0,255,0), -1)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('gospel', gospel)
cv2.imshow('diff',diff)
cv2.imshow('filled gospel',filled_gospel)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

When I do the above steps, you can see some translational differences between the 'gospel' and the taken image. What would be the best way to combat this as I only want to get the differences in the black of the letter, not how well it is aligned?

Comment: After some more research, I came across an algorithm that might work called "Zernike Moments". If I use this, I should be able to determine as to whether or not the image is moved. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/04/07/building-pokedex-python-indexing-sprites-using-shape-descriptors-step-3-6/

Comment: Pad each example image with the color of the background so it is 150% or even 200% as large in each dimension (or at least as much as you think the offsets are). Then use template matching to locate where the reference (gold standard) image best matches in the padded example. Then crop the padded example at those coordinates and of the size of the reference. Finally do your ssim processing.

Comment: @fmw42 What do you mean by offsets? Do you mean the distance between the edges of the image and the edges of the letters? Then have an equally sized (blown up) template to pattern match against the padded example, if I'm reading your response correctly.

Comment: The offset is what you showed. They seems to be translated (shifted) a bit. You need to find the offset by the procedure I specified and then do your comparison. I am suggesting that you pad the example images. For simplicity, double the dimensions. Then do template matching of the reference to find where it is located in the padded examples. Get the match location and crop the padded example at that location as the upper left corner, but of the size of the template so that the cropped size is the same as the template. Then do your ssim comparison.

Comment: My process is simply aligning the two images as best as possible and its template matching score is also a measure of good a match they are. There is not a simple way to ignore the shifts. You have to align the two images before doing ssim or you could do a simple image differencing (after normalizing) at that point as an alternate to ssim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do template matching and differencing in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the reference and example images
- Pad the example image to twice its dimensions with its background gray color.
- Do template matching with the reference to find the best match location and match score.
- Crop the padded example image with its top left corner at the match location, but the size of the reference image
- Get the absolute difference image
- Save results

Reference:

[image]

Example:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read reference and convert to gray
ref = cv2.imread('reference.png')
ref_gray = cv2.cvtColor(ref, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hr, wr = ref_gray.shape

# read example and convert to gray
ex = cv2.imread('example.png')
ex_gray = cv2.cvtColor(ex, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
he, we = ex_gray.shape

# pad the example to double its dimensions with gray=190
color=190
wp = we // 2
hp = he // 2
ex_gray = cv2.copyMakeBorder(ex_gray, hp,hp,wp,wp, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=color)

# do template matching
corrimg = cv2.matchTemplate(ref_gray,ex_gray,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(corrimg)
max_val_corr = '{:.3f}'.format(max_val)
print("correlation: " + max_val_corr)
xx = max_loc[0]
yy = max_loc[1]
print('x_match_loc =',xx,'y_match_loc =',yy)

# crop the padded example image at top left corner of xx,yy and size hr x wr
ex_gray_crop = ex_gray[yy:yy+hr, xx:xx+wr]

# get absolute difference image
ref_grayf = ref_gray.astype(np.float32)
ex_gray_cropf = ex_gray_crop.astype(np.float32)
diff = 255 - np.abs(cv2.add(ref_gray, -ex_gray_crop))

# compute mean of diff
mean = cv2.mean(diff)[0]
print("mean of diff in range 0 to 100 =",mean)

cv2.imshow('ref_gray', ref_gray)
cv2.imshow('ex_gray', ex_gray)
cv2.imshow('ex_gray_crop', ex_gray_crop)
cv2.imshow('correlation image', corrimg)
cv2.imshow('diff', diff)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save results
cv2.imwrite('reference_gray.jpg', ref_gray)
cv2.imwrite('example_gray_padded.jpg', ex_gray)
cv2.imwrite('reference_example_correlation.jpg', (255*corrimg).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite('example_gray_padded_cropped.jpg', ex_gray_crop)
cv2.imwrite('reference_example_diff.jpg', diff)
```

Example padded:

[image]

Correlation Image showing locations of best match:

[image]

Match Results:

```
correlation: 0.969
x_match_loc = 10 y_match_loc = 9

mean of diff in range 0 to 100 = 1.3956887102667155
```

Example cropped to align with reference:

[image]

Diff image (white is where they differ):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough example and explanations! This worked perfectly.